# sed digits with optional decimal and backreference

Tags: regex, sed

I have simple input like this :

```
11111(n)
222222(p)
33333333(:)
```

I can use sed backreference to swap parenthesis with digits like this :

```
sed -e 's/\([[:digit:]]*\)\((.*)\)/\2 \1/' file
```

which produce

```
(n) 11111
(p) 222222
(:) 33333333
```

It's cool !

But things became more difficult with potential decimal digits, like this

```
11111(n)
11111.111(n)
2222222.22(p)
33.3333333(:)
```

I've try many commands, like

```
sed -e 's/\([[:digit:]]*(\.[[:digit:]]*?)\)\((.*)\)/\2 \1/' file
sed -e 's/\([[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*?)\)\((.*)\)/\2 \1/' file
sed -e 's/\([[:digit:]]*\.*[[:digit:]]*)\)\((.*)\)/\2 \1/' file
sed -e 's/\([[:digit:]]*.*[[:digit:]]*)\)\((.*)\)/\2 \1/' file
```

Output desired :

```
(n) 11111
(n) 11111.111
(p) 2222222.22
(:) 33.3333333
```

Note that digits can be arbitrary long (1 to n digits), and decimal mark (.) and decimal digits are optional.

Furthermore, `sed` don't seem to have `\d` shorthand, as pointed in [stackexchange](https://superuser.com/questions/513412/how-to-match-digits-followed-by-a-dot-using-sed)

Comment: another question : when 2 answers are awesome (well documented, clear, ...) which one am I supposed to accept ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets quite simple when you know what to match in the POSIX bracket expression with `[:digit:]`. All you need to do is include another `.` so that the bracket expression would mean set of digits along with `.`,

```
sed 's/\([[:digit:].]*\)\((.*)\)/\2 \1/' file
```

Also you don't need to mention `-e`, because `sed` by default operates in BRE (Basic Regular Expressions) mode and with `-E` the ERE (Extended Regular Expression) mode is enabled. Also `\d` is not a valid regular expression construct used by any versions of `sed` (POSIX, GNU or FreeBSD) to match digits. I suppose it is supported in the PCRE library in which you could use `perl`

```
perl -lne 'print "$2 $1" if /(\d+\.?\d*).*(\([^)]*\))/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^([.[:digit:]]+)(\([^)]*\))/\2 \1/g' file
```

```
(n) 11111
(n) 11111.111
(p) 2222222.22
(:) 33.3333333
```

Here `[.[:digit:]]+` will match 1+ of any digit or dot character.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use simple collection?

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9.]*\)\((.*)\)/\2 \1/' file
```

Since [0-9] and [:digit:] are <strike>basically the same</strike>, but when you want include other character, former one is more intuitive.

Given a second thought, in which I see that you were trying to match the legitimate number, i.e. no point or only one point, thus improved sed one would be:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)(\(.*\))/\3 \1/' file
```

-r to support +? in RE and switch parentheses' escape around.
Or use perl to avoid all those RE extension confusion:

```
perl -lne 'print "$3 $1" if /(\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*(\(.*?\))/' file
```

Update: 
As Benjamin W. mentioned in comments, [0-9] and [[:digit:]] are not the same, so if you want to consider possible digits in other languages, the sed one should be:

```
sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?)(\(.*\))/\3 \1/' file
```

Comment: `[0-9]` is potentially something other than `[0123456789]`, depending on your locale; `[[:digit:]]` is locale-safe.

Comment: @BenjaminW.  Could you give an example? Thanks.

Comment: [This Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414226/difference-between-0-9-digit-and-d) has a great explanation.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks, it happens that I just found this one and reading it now. Thanks for the headsup and your help :)