# awk sed backreference csv file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

A question to extend previous one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53784190/sed-digits-with-optional-decimal-and-backreference). (I prefer asking new question rather editing first one. I may be wrong)

EDIT : ok, I was wrong, I should edit my first question. My bad (SO question is an art, difficult to master)

I have csv file, with semi-column as field delimiter. Here is an extract of csv file :

`...;field;(:);10000(n,d);(:);field;....
...;field;123.12(b);123(a);123.00(:);....`

Here is the desired output :

`...;field;(:);(n,d) 10000;(:);field;....
...;field;(b) 123.12;(a) 123;(:) 123.00;....`

I search a solution to swap 2 patterns in each field.

pattern 1 : any digit, with optional decimal mark (.) and optional decimal digit

e.g : 1 / 1111.00 / 444444444.3 / 32 / 32.6666666 / 1.0 / ....

pattern 2 : any string that begin with left parenthesis, follow by one or more character, ending with right parenthesis

e.g : (n,a,p) / (:) / (llll) / (d) / (123) / (1;2;3) ...

Solutions provided in first question are right for simple file that contain only one column. If I try the solution within csv file, I face multiple failures.

So I try `awk` similar solution, which is (I think) more "column-oriented".

I have try

```
awk -F";" '{print gensub(/([[:digit:].]*)(\(.*\))/, "\\2 \\1", "g")}' file
```

I though by fixing field delimiter (;), "my regex swap" will succes in every field. It was a mistake.

Here is an exemple of failure

```
;(:);7320000(n,d);(:)
```

desired output --> `;(:);(n,d) 7320000;(:)`

My questions (finally) : why `awk` fail when it success with one-column file. what is the best tool to face this challenge ?

1. sed with very long regex ?
2. awk with very long regex ?
3. for loop ?
4. other tools ?

PS : I know I am not clear. I have 2 problems (English language, technical limitations). Sorry.

Comment: If you prefer to ask a new question, please make sure that it is self contained.

Comment: Please keep your question to the point, I second hek2mgl sir, your question is not clear. So try to edit it with adding more details.

Comment: `;(:);7320000(n,d);(;)` please post the format of the input file or post a representative part from the input. Do the `;`, `:` `(` `)` `,` change or are delimeters? What does change between outputs? What is the set of allowed characters? It's indefinitely hard to guess a regex to match an unknown format. This format is different from `11111.111(n)`. If you work per lines basis only, `sed` is probably the simplest solution, if you want ex. sum columns (not work only per lines only) then `awk` comes in.

Comment: In your "example of failure", was the change of the semicolon to colon intentional? (in the last pair of brackets)

Comment: I edit my question. I hope my post is representative. My csv file have semi-column as field delimiter. All other characters are not field delimiter. In each field, csv file can contain (in theory) every character : coma, single or double-quote, ... but no semi-colum, or there will be double-quoted. OK, I stop, I am more and more unclear ... :(

Comment: @TrebuchetMS : my bad, typo error, I have edited my question.

Comment: @oguzismail : your solution work perfectly in my csv. Many thanks ! May I ask some explanations about the second group ? (([^)]\+). I am not sure to understand correctly (to be honest, I don't understand at all ...). And why switching [:digit:] to [0-9.] ? Again, tx you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "question" is far too long, cluttered, and containing too many separate questions to wade through but here's how to get the output you want from the input you provided with any sed:

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9][0-9.]*\)\(([^)]*)\)/\2 \1/g' file
...;field;(:);(n,d) 10000;(:);field;....
...;field;(b) 123.12;(a) 123;(:) 123.00;....
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, when parsing simple delimetered files without any quoted values, usually awk comes to the rescue:

```
awk -vFS=';' -vOFS=';' '{
    for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) {
        split($i, t, "(")
        if (length(t[1]) != 0 && length(t[2]) != 0) {
            $i="("t[2]" "t[1]
        }
    }
    print
}' <<EOF
...;field;(:);10000(n,d);(:);field;....
...;field;123.12(b);123(a);123.00(:);....
EOF
```

However this will fail if fields are quoted, ie. the separator `;` comes inside the values...

1. First we set input and output seapartor as `;`
2. We iterate through all the fields in the line `for (i = 1; i < NF; i++)`
3. We split the line over `(` character
4. If the first field splitted over `(` is nonzero length and the second field has also nonzero length
5. We swap the firelds for this fields and add a space (we also remember about the removed `(` on the beginning).
6. And then the line get's `print`ed.

A solution using `sed` and `xargs`, but you need to know the number of fields in advance:

```
{
    sed 's/;/\n/g' |
    sed 's/\([^(]\{1,\}\)\((.*)\)/\2 \1/' |
    xargs -d '\n' -n7 -- printf "%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s\n"
} <<EOF
...;field;(:);10000(n,d);(:);field;....
...;field;123.12(b);123(a);123.00(:);....
EOF
```

1. For each `;` i do a newline
2. For each line i substitute the string with at least on character before `(` and a string inside `)`.
3. I then merge 7 lines using `;` as separator with xargs and printf.

Comment: thanks. So, what do you suggest for csv file with quoted strings that may embed field delimiter ? It may help me as I also work with this type of file.

Comment: I suggest a csv aware tool to substitute the separator for an unreadable character (ex. `\x01` or `\xfa`) with `csvtool` or similar and then parse as normal, then substitute the separator back.

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton, didn't knew that! ; )

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)(\([^)]*\))/\3 \1/g' file
```

Look for group of numbers (possibly with a decimal point) followed by a pair of parens and rearrange them in the desired fashion, globally through out each line.